# How to avoid Class not found exception in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing a sample map application using map API V-2. This app runs properly on one of device having jelly been 4.3 but, when I test this app on another device having Gingerbread 2.3.5, the app crashes and shows exception below.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line#2: Error inflating class fragment.
```

and

```
ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik..............
```

Please guide me that how to run the successfully on  Gingerbread devices. Thanks in advance.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Here is my java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add android.support.v4 library to your Project and also extends your MainActivity to FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to add the support library for supportin map in previous version android devices and the xml for that should be like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Then in map activity you should get the map instance by this way:--

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

**Note:**

Your map activity should extend this **FragmentActivity** class is necessary.ie.

```
 public class GetDirectionActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add support v4 library to do this and extend MainActivity with FragmentActivity.

Check out following link

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and select properties. Now go to Order and Export then check the support v4 library option. It will not show exception anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate `Google Maps API V2` in an application that will run on API prior to 11 you will need to change you code from using `MapFragment` and a simple `Activity` to `SupportMapFragment` and a `FragmentActivity`. You can find the full guide of integration in this blog post guide I wrote:

[Google Maps API V2 Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)